# Lua Script Error

Tags: lua, scenarios

Situation:

I want to save the record of a data which is a value of the sensor in the certain file.

Code is..

```
--Header file
require("TIMER")
require("IPBOX")
require("ANALOG_IN")
require("LOG")

function OnExit()
print("Exit code...do something")
end

function main()
timer = "Timer"
local analogsensor_1 = "AIR_1"
local analogsensor_2 = "AIR_2"
local timestr = os.data("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")


-- open the file for writing binary data
local filehandle = io.open("collection_of_data.txt", "a")


while true do 
    valueOfSensor_1 = ANALOG_IN.readAnalogIn(analogsensor_1);
    valueOfSensor_2 = ANALOG_IN.readAnalogIn(analogsensor_2);

    if (valueOfSensor_1 > 0 and valueOfSensor_2 > 0) then

        -- save values of sensors           
        filehandle:write(timestr, " -The Value of the Sensors: ", tostring(valueOfSensor_1), tostring(valueOfSensor_2)"\n");

        -- save values using rolling log appender:          
        LOG.log_event( ScenarioLoggerDevicenameInDeviceList, " -The Value of the Sensors: ", tostring(valueOfSensor_1), tostring(valueOfSensor_2), "any other string you wish to add", "etc", "etc")
        LOG.log_event( ScenarioLoggerDevicenameInDeviceList, " -The Value of the Sensors: ", tostring(valueOfSensor_1))
        print("Hello3"..valueOfSensor_1)
    end

TIMER.sleep(timer,500)
end

-- close the file
filehandle:close()

end 

print("start main")
main()
```

In this line:

```
filehandle:write(timestr, " -The Value of the Sensors: ", tostring(valueOfSensor_1), tostring(valueOfSensor_2)"\n");
```

I get an error:

```
"attemp to index global 'filehandle' (a nil value)"
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

`io.open` returns `nil` if it cannot open the file. This can be due to "file not found", "permissions denied" and maybe other reasons. To figure out the problem, `io.open` has a second return value, which lets you inspect the error (in fact, it even returns a third value, which is an error-code integer - but its meaning is system dependent).

Change:

```
local filehandle = io.open("collection_of_data.txt", "a")
```

to

```
local filehandle, message = io.open("collection_of_data.txt", "a")
if not filehandle then
    print(message)
end
```

You can also use the following Lua idiom:

```
local filehandle = assert(io.open("collection_of_data.txt", "a"))
```

This will do the same. If the first argument to `assert` is `nil`, then the second argument (the second return value of `io.open` will be printed. If the first argument is not `nil`, it will simply be returned.